# Иногда не срабатывает клик pyautogui

Tags: python, клавиатура, pyautogui

Я пишу софты на python и столкнулся  проблемой. Сейчас опишу:
Есть софт, который по нажатию клавиши запускается и сам начинает выполнять за меня действия(в данном случае это зажать s, через 0.25 сек отпустить, нажать shift и сразу отпустить, кликнуть правой кнопкой мыши и повторять до того момента, пока я не нажму клавишу для остановки его работы.)
Так вот. Проблема заключается в том, что не всегда софт кликает правой кнопкой мыши.
Пример: софт начал работу, повторил действие несколько раз, а потом наступает переломный момент: он выполнил зажатие s и отпустил эту клавишу, нажал shift, отпустил, и вдруг не нажал правой кнопкой мыши. Но не надо думать что выполнение кода просто остановилось. Нет. Он продолжает нажимать s и shift, только вот из-за того что он не кликнул весь процесс ломается, и в игре, конечно, это заканчивается плохо.
Ожидалось, что все будет нормально, но не тут то было.
Сам код:

```
import os
import keyboard
import pyautogui as pyi
from time import sleep


keyboard.wait("0")
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("-"):
        keyboard.press("w")
        sleep(0.2)
        keyboard.release("w")
        break
    pyi.rightClick()
    keyboard.press("s")
    sleep(0.25)
    keyboard.release("s")
    keyboard.press("shift")
    sleep(0.05)
    keyboard.release("shift")
    pyi.rightClick()
    keyboard.press("s")
    sleep(0.25)
    keyboard.release("s")
    keyboard.press("shift")
    sleep(0.05)
    keyboard.release("shift")
    pyi.rightClick()
    
os.system("python start/soft.py")
```

> Если что, `os.system("python start/soft.py")` это запуск этого же файла

Comment: Забыл сказать, что нужно быстро выполнять все действия, иначе от этого кода не будет толку.

Answer (score 0):

Видимо проблема в том, что это не питон "не всегда кликает правой кнопкой мыши", а игра не успевает отработать. Пробуй увеличивать временные интервалы (вплоть до нескольких секунд). Возможно следует проверять на экране появления какого-то признака (кнопки, иконки, надписи) при помощи pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen.

Comment: Так и проблема то в том, что нужно быстро выполнить все действия, а если будет большая задержка то и толку то ноль от моего кода. Вручную быстрее будет. В игре все окей, остается кликнуть правой кнопкой мыши только и все. Ничего не мешает, прицел наводится правильно.

Comment: может после rightClick тоже ставить паузу? Там еще пару мест таких есть (без паузы).